# Output is null, when getting the nodeValue

Tags: javascript, html, xml, null, nodevalue

I'm getting the value of a node by this code in javascript,

```
function show(){
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName("allowance")[0];
        var y = x.nodeValue;
        alert(y);
    }
```

from this xml in html.

```
<xml style="display: none">
        <students id="lul">
            <student>
                <name>Mark Fajardo</name>
                <allowance>9999</allowance>
            </student>
            <student>
                <name>Rencie Macale</name>
                <allowance>20</allowance>
            </student>
        </students>
    </xml>
```

But the output that alert projects is just null. Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you can use innerHTML like this

```
y = document.getElementsByTagName("allowance")[0].innerHTML;
alert(y);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I've looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `textContent` to get the text from the XML tag, as `nodeValue` only returns the text value of a **text node** in XML, on **element** nodes, the `nodeValue` property is always `null`.

```js
function show() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("allowance")[0];
  var y = x.textContent;
  console.log(y);
}

show()
```

```html
<xml style="display: none">
  <students id="lul">
    <student>
      <name>Mark Fajardo</name>
      <allowance>9999</allowance>
    </student>
    <student>
      <name>Arabella Raymundo</name>
      <allowance>20</allowance>
    </student>
  </students>
</xml>
```

Comment: Sure, `innerHTML` isn't really the correct method to use on something that isn't HTML, but XML, but it probably works in most browsers.